# Swap values of two columns of dataframe if conditions apply (Python 3)

Tags: python, group-by, nested, average

I want to calculate the average of countX for all rows that have similar address1 and address2 or for the cases where the address values are inverted. That is, address1=ad3 and address2=ad1 is similar to address1=ad1 and address2=ad3.

For instance,
If the input is (csv file):

```
ID    COUNTX     ADDRESS1     ADDRESS2  
1        21       ad3       ad1
2        22       ad1       ad3
3        23       ad2       ad4
4        25       ad2       ad4
5        25       ad1       ad5
6        23       ad5       ad1
7        22       ad1       ad4
8        21       ad4       ad6
```

The output should be:

```
ID    COUNTX     ADDRESS1     ADDRESS2     AVG_cOUNTX   
1        21       ad3       ad1       21.5
3        23       ad2       ad4       24
5        25       ad1       ad5       24
7        22       ad1       ad4       22
8        21       ad4       ad6       21
```

I have tried to do the following:

1. Use a nested loop, to swap the column values when I find that address1_of_a_row =address2_another_row and address2_of_a_row=address1_another_row
2. Group by address1 and address2 and calculate AVG.

Since I have large datasets (1-3 million), this needs to be very efficient (which is not the case for my code).

I am using Python 3.7 and the pandas package 0.22.
Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way. There might be other more elegant solutions but this should do the job and will be far more efficient than a nested loop.

First create two additional columns which we'll call `'ADDRESS_1'` and `'ADDRESS_2'`. The former will always contain whichever address comes first lexicographically, allowing you to then group the data as desired on these new columns, since you no longer have to worry about the case where addresses are inverted being treated separately.

```
df['ADDRESS_1'] = df[['ADDRESS1', 'ADDRESS2']].values.min(axis=1)
df['ADDRESS_2'] = df[['ADDRESS1', 'ADDRESS2']].values.max(axis=1)
```

Then use `groupby`:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['ADDRESS_1', 'ADDRESS_2']).mean()[['COUNTX']].reset_index()
```

Results:

```
  ADDRESS_1 ADDRESS_2  COUNTX
0       ad1       ad3    21.5
1       ad1       ad4    22.0
2       ad1       ad5    24.0
3       ad2       ad4    24.0
4       ad4       ad6    21.0
```

This isn't identical to your example output, as the order of the addresses is lost, but from your description of the problem I didn't think this was important. Please comment below if that's not the case.

Comment: Order is not important, thank you very much @thesilkworm